# Nginx deployed Angular frontend does not connect to DRF backend

Tags: django, angular, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have deployed drf backend and angular frontend in the same aws instance, using Nginx and gunicron for the drf and Nginx for the angular. I tested the drf API using postman it works fine but the angular frontend doesn't connect to the API, the site works but cannot connect to the backend API. It shows

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://3.129.126.13:8080/api/products?search=asus&page=1' from origin 'http://3.129.126.13' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have whitelisted the frontend address in the python app setting.

Frontend is hosted at 80 and the backend is at 8080.

server block for the backend:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name 0.0.0.0;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
            root /home/ubuntu/Sheradam_backend;
    }

    location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/Sheradam_backend/Sheradam_backend.sock;

    }
}
```

server block for frontend

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name Sheradambd.com;
    root /home/ubuntu/Sheradam_frontend/dist/SheraDam;
    server_tokens off;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        # First attempt to server request as file, then         
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.          
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

python app setting:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://3.129.126.13',
)
```

Comment: the solution was found here 

https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was found here enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html